# Small part of subfloor on exterior wall rotten

Tags: subfloor

I am ripping up carpet in a room to replace with vinyl planking, and found this 1 foot by about 2-4 inches of subfloor near exterior wall rotted leaving a hole there basically after i took out as much as I could with my hands.

Question is how hard is this to replace/fix, how much should I estimate it to cost, and should I get a professional since this is an exterior wall? (I have no experience with subflooring)

https://postimg.cc/gallery/X5pZcFz

Thanks!

Comment: What is access like underneath?

Comment: finished basement so no access unless i cut through ceiling

Comment: The answer from @popham is exceptionally thorough, but the scope of this repair might be impacted by what you haven’t seen in the wall. Suggest you open up a wide section of drywall and see what your framing (studs, plate) look like. This will also probably help you understand and fix the root cause.

Comment: You need to open it up and see the damage. Do not just repair what you see as the damage is almost certainly more than that. You also need to fix the leak that allowed that to happen. I would expect you need to remove all the drywall up to the window and at least one stud past the windows/jacks/kings (probably 16"), but the cause could be coming from above and it simply was pooling at that spot. Is there any evidence of water damage at the ceiling?

Answer (score 1):

I expect that a typical professional will use a circular saw and oscillating multitool to remove rectangular chunks for replacement. Then he'll cut patches to fill the holes, filling in without much thought to anything but gravity loads. I suspect that this happens all the time across the US without any complaints as long as the job is a single family dwelling. Translating that process to a cost is out of bounds for this site (because the cost changes with time and region). If you know your region, though, then decide a quick, easy process to restore the floor as a walking surface, and estimate the cost.

Technically the subfloor is part of a "floor diaphragm," where losing continuity with the sheathing under the wall's bottom plate is a structural problem. For two little spots around the whole perimeter of the structure, it's not a big deal. More important is mitigating the root cause to prevent the problem from spreading. If the damage is more extensive or you're a by-the-book person, then you would want to repair the diaphragm in addition to the walking surface.

For brace walls running perpendicular to the joists, cut bad OSB back to sound material and end at the midline of a joist at each end. Following the nailing schedule prescribed at [IRC R602.3](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P1/chapter-6-wall-construction#IRC2021P1_Pt03_Ch06_SecR602.3), install blocking between the joists and just interior to the wall's bottom plate. The same tables will provide you the nailing schedule for your patches (including the edge that sit atop the freshly installed blocking). Remember that panel products have a "strength axis," so cutting patches correctly requires a bit of thinking.

For brace walls running parallel to joists, I believe that you would technically need an engineer's input. Without access from below, my instinct is an L1×1×1/8 steel angle face nailed to the inside edge of the wall's bottom plate. Toeing the angle inward would provide a bearing surface for the floor patch and also "collects" the diaphragm shear into the brace wall. Assuming, of course, that the subfloor is adequately fastened to the steel angle. With access from below, my instinct is a 2x6 laying flat and nailed to the underside of the bottom plate (with a floor sheathing thickness spacer).

In your position, I would want a familiar professional who will predictably choose the solution from paragraph 1. If your professional chooses the by-the-book solution and you estimated cost based on paragraph 1, then I expect that your job could turn acrimonious.